# Functoriality of first homology of group

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Hello  I have the next doubt:

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $T:=T(A)=\left\{\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    u & 0 \\
    0  & u^{-1} \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\;:\;u\in A^{\ast}\right\}$  the subgroup of diagonable matrices of $SL_{2}(A)$ where $A^{\ast}$ is the group of units.

Now let $w=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0&-1 \\
    1&0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$ in $SL_{2}(A)$, we have that $w$ acts on $T$ by conjugation.

My doubt is to know how the induced morphism in the first homology by the conjugation  $w_{1}:H_{1}(T,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_{1}(T,\mathbb{Z})$ is the map $u\mapsto u^{-1}$.

I was trying to do it by using the isomorphism $T=T^{ab}\cong H_{1}(T,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_{1}(T,\mathbb{Z})\cong T^{ab}=T$ which I can get the result by using the bar resolution and the isomorphism $A^{\ast}\cong T(A)$, however  I was told that by using the functoriality of the first homology is enough without using direct calculations.

The only thing I think is that the isomorphism  $H_{1}(G,\mathbb{Z})\cong G^{ab}$ is natural.

if the latter is true, it is enough by using the conjugation map $t_{w}:T\rightarrow T$ which is only inversion in this particular case.  I would like to know  if that is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question specifically is about. Are you asking whether the isomorphism $H_1(T;\mathbb Z)\cong T^{ab}$ is natural ? If so, then the answer is yes.

Comment: My doubt was "Why the functoriality is enough  ?"  That's why  I wrote my idea about the naturality of the isomorphism . Thank you!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Is $T=T(A)$? Is $w$ acting on $T(A)$ by conjugation?